# Encapsulating a multi-threaded operation in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, osgi, threadpool

I have a situation where I have a large number of classes that need to do file (read only) access.  This is part of a web app running on top of OSGI, so there will be a lot of concurrent needs to access.

So I'm building an OSGI service to access the file system for all the other pieces that will need it and provide a centralized access as this also simplifies configuration of file locations, etc.

It occurs to me that a multi-threaded approach makes the most sense along with a thread pool.

So the question is this:

If I do this and I have a service with an interface like:
FileService.getFileAsClass(class);

and the method getFileAsClass(class) looks kinda like this: (this is a sketch it may not be perfect java code)

```
public < T> T getFileAsClass(Class< T> clazz) {
Future<InputStream> classFuture = threadpool.submit(new Callable< InputStream>() {
        /* initialization block */
        {
        //any setup from configs.
        }

        /* implement Callable */
        public InputStream call() {
                         InputStream stream = //new inputstream from file location;
                         boolean giveUp = false;

                 while(null == stream && !giveUp) {
                             //Code that tries to read in the file 4
                             // times with a Thread.sleep() then gives up
                             // this is here t make sure we aren't busy updating file.
                         }
                         return stream;
        }
    });
     //once we have the file, convert it and return it.
     return InputStreamToClassConverter< T>.convert(classFuture.get());
}
```

Will that correctly wait until the relevant operation is done to call InputStreamtoClassConverter.convert?

This is my first time writing multithreaded java code so I'm not sure what I can expect for some of the behavior.  I don't care about order of which threads complete, only that the file handling is handled async and once that file pull is done, then and only then is the Converter used.

Comment: What the hell should "null == InputStream" be???

Comment: Why do you want to try 4 times updating the file? Usually, when it fails, it will also fail when you try again.

Comment: @isnot2bad sorry like I said wasn't 'real' java code, just sketching out meaning.  I updated the code to reflect what I meant.

As for updating the file, this is gonna be on a server where new files are getting pushed and updated regularly. So it may be that the file read will fail, but then a second later it will succeed.

Comment: the calling thread does nothing between `threadpool.submit` and `classFuture.get()`. As a result, your program is not really multithreaded. It can work even better if `getFileAsClass` do exactly what `call` does.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov read the comments, this is just a sketch.  Note in the comment that it tries to read files, etc, I just left all that code out because it wasn't relevant to the question.

Comment: There is no point creating a Future and then immediately calling get() on that Future. This causes your calling thread to block until the future's result is available. In other words its exactly the same as if you did all the IO directly in the calling thread!

Comment: @NeilBartlett that actually answers the question I was trying to understand about how future's work, though apparently nobody actually really understood my question as I intended.